# R lapply delayed evaluation?

Tags: r, lapply

I'm having trouble with lapply seemingly delaying evaluation of my function and I get a result list full of the last cell, however if I add a print statement to the apply function it works fine (this is simplified example from my case):

```
p <- list ();
a <- function(..., s = function(p) p) {
  fs <- list(...);
  p <<- c(p, lapply(setNames(1:length(fs), names(fs)),
                    function(i) (function(n, f) {
                                   function() s(f)
                                 }) (names(fs)[i], fs[[i]])))
}
a(g = function() 2, r = function() 5)
```

Evaluating `lapply(p, function(p) p())` gives

```
$g
function () 
5

$r
function () 
5
```

However if I add a print statement to the very inner function everything is fine:

```
p <- list ();
a <- function(..., s = function(p) p) {
  fs <- list(...);
  p <<- c(p, lapply(setNames(1:length(fs), names(fs)),
                    function(i) (function(n, f) {
                                   print(n);
                                   function() s(f)
                                 }) (names(fs)[i], fs[[i]])))
}
a(g = function() 2, r = function() 5)
```

Evaluating same `lapply(p, function(p) p())` gives expected

```
$g
function () 
2

$r
function () 
5
```

I don't understand how this is happening or what I can do about it, this is with R version 3.1.1

Comment: R uses 'lazy evaluation'. Putting the print(n) in there has the effect of `force()`-ing the lookup and evaluation of 'n'. You can use `force` instead.

Comment: How can I force evaluation without printing

Comment: the argument `n` is a promise, that is not evaluated until it is used.  You can use `force(n)`, to force the evaluation, which is standard procedure for a factory function that takes parameters which are scoped to the return function via lexical scoping.  See the [R language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects) for details.

Comment: As I said. Use the `force`. Look it up, it's a function.

Comment: I'm sorry I need to learn to read. Many thanks, it works